# how do I save the query result to file in rethinkdb

Tags: xml, json, rethinkdb

I need to save all / export results generated by rql in the browser while running rethinkdb. Most of the times, I feel the browser gets overwhelmed with data. Instead of displaying the content in browser, is there a way to redirect / save the results directly to a json/xml file on disk ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct/simple way of saving your query results directly from the data explorer in the browser.

If you're doing a large query and want to save it to a json, I'd recommend using a REPL and just saving it. If you're using Python, that would look something like this:

```
import json
import rethinkdb as r

f = open('/results.json', 'w')
// Convert the cursor into a list and then turn it into a JSON string
f.write(json.dumps(list(r.table('people').run(conn) )))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a slightly different approach, which avoids converting the result to a list (depending on the size of the result, this could become rather memory intensive, for all I know):

```
import json
import rethinkdb as r

f = open('result.json', 'w')
cur = <your query>
for row in cur:
    f.write(json.dumps(row))
```